# ORACLE SQL-How can i search between COLUMN_NAME in a Table and get value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with `Calendarweeks`. I want the values ​​of between 2 `column_name`. I use 2 dropdown for `column_name`. I have already tried (see below) but unfortunately not success. Could anyone help me, please? Thank you

```
SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID) 
  FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ALSI_TEST_DELETE' 
   AND COLUMN_NAME BETWEEN :dropdown1 AND :dropdown2

>>>Results:  01, 02, 03, 04 (But without Values, only COLUMN_NAME. I want Values and COLUMN_NAME)
```

[image]

Comment: Please show sample of your table and your expected output

Comment: This sounds like a really strange data model if you need to do things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `UNPIVOT` for your problem:

```
WITH ALSI_TEST_DELETE AS (SELECT 7 "01", 8 "02", 9 "03", 10 "04", 11 "05", 12 "06", 1 ID FROM dual)
SELECT ID, COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_VALUE
  FROM ALSI_TEST_DELETE
UNPIVOT 
 (COLUMN_VALUE
  FOR COLUMN_ID IN ("01","02","03","04","05","06"))
 WHERE COLUMN_ID BETWEEN '01' AND '04'
```

This query might give you a start and you might end up with something like the following:

```
SELECT ID, LISTAGG(column_id||': '||column_value,', ') within GROUP (ORDER BY column_id)
  FROM ALSI_TEST_DELETE
UNPIVOT 
 (COLUMN_VALUE
  FOR COLUMN_ID IN ("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53"))
 WHERE COLUMN_ID BETWEEN :dropdown1 AND :dropdown2
 GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Hi thanks for Answer. But its not dynamic.for example: SELECT 7 "01", 8 "02", 9 "03", 10 "04", 11 "05", 12 "06", 1 ID FROM dual), I cant write 7,8,9..., because the values ​​can change. And I have "01" to "53" column

Comment: That is just an example with your test data - Skip the `WITH`-Line for your tests. You have to specify all your 53 columns then in the `FOR COLUMN_ID IN (...)` line.

Comment: Its worked. Can you help me for this code? @Radagast81
UPDATE ALSI_TEST_DELETE SET (SELECT  LISTAGG(column_id,', ') within GROUP (ORDER BY column_id)
  FROM ALSI_TEST_DELETE
UNPIVOT 
 (COLUMN_VALUE
  FOR COLUMN_ID IN ("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06"))
 WHERE COLUMN_ID BETWEEN :dropdown1 AND :dropdown2 and ID = 1) = (SELECT  LISTAGG(column_value,', ') within GROUP (ORDER BY column_id)
  FROM ALSI_TEST_DELETE
UNPIVOT 
 (COLUMN_VALUE
  FOR COLUMN_ID IN ("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06"))
 WHERE COLUMN_ID BETWEEN :dropdown3 AND :dropdown4 and ID = 1) where ID = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Seems You want such a query as below :

```
select listagg(column_name,', ') within group (order by column_id)
    as "My Columns List" 
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'ALSI_TEST_DELETE'
   and column_id between ( select column_id 
                             from user_tab_columns 
                            where table_name = 'ALSI_TEST_DELETE' 
                              and column_name = 'COL1' )
                     and ( select column_id 
                             from user_tab_columns 
                            where table_name = 'ALSI_TEST_DELETE' 
                              and column_name = 'COL4' );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=74de0cab9ab0496400541f388ea74605)</kbd>

More elegant way to be considered :

```
with utc as
(
 select table_name as tab_name,
        max(case when column_name = 'COL1' then column_id end) as col1,
        max(case when column_name = 'COL4' then column_id end) as col2 
   from user_tab_columns 
  where table_name = 'ALSI_TEST_DELETE'
  group by table_name
)
select listagg(column_name,', ') within group (order by column_id)
    as "My Columns List" 
  from user_tab_columns
  cross join utc
 where table_name = utc.tab_name
   and column_id between utc.col1 and utc.col2;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for Answer. But i dont use always COL1 und COL4. Its dynamic and its from Dropdown. It may be too between COL33 and COL53.

Comment: @sqlhunter of course, you may try even by other columns as boundaries.

Comment: Isn't the real problem to get the data values together with the column names?

Comment: @Radagast81 says *"But without Values, only COLUMN_NAME"*

Comment: I want values with COLUMN_NAme

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan second sentence states he wants the values with the column names...